# "overlay" Strings algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, combinations

Is there a known algorithm for combining strings in a way, so that what most oft the input strings have in common is put in the resulting string? What I mean is this:

```
input-1: "This is a Tsst"

input-2: "This is Test"

input-3: "Thi5 ia a Test"


result: "This is a Test"
```

The length in words and characters of the inputs is varying, which creates the problem for me.

Comment: Do you necessarily want to output on of the original input, as in your example ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: sorry, I mispelled a word. My question is : is the result exactly one of the input ? In your example, the result is input-2. So do you have to choose among the input, or can it be a combination of the different inputs ?

Comment: No, it's a mix between what is most common in all of the inputs. In input 2 the 'a' is missing, but in 1 and 3 it is there, therefore it will make it to the result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's rtather involved.

You do a multiple alignment of the string sequences using Clustal or a variant. Then you read off the consensus sequence. Clustal accepts a scoring matrix, which is intended for protein sequences, but could be used for English letters (k is similar to c, 5 to s and so on).